# Can't import Traveling Salesman Problem in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to run the TSP in NetworkX, and I'm following their code from https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.traveling_salesman.traveling_salesman_problem.html

However, whenever I try to import the module, it gives me an error.

For example:

`import networkx.approximation as na`
gives the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx.approximation'`

And

`import networkx.algorithms.approximation as naa`

`tsp = naa.traveling_salesman_problem`

Gives the following error:

`AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.approximation' has no attribute 'traveling_salesman_problem'`

I'm copying the code directly from the manual so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: import networkx as nx;  
nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone who understands pip better may please jump in here.

I had the same errors as you mentioned and checked my version of networkx (which was 2.5.2) and apperantly the TSP part was added later. The current version mentioned on their [website](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/install.html) is 2.6.2. Through `pip install networkx` only 2.5.2 was installed. But with `pip install --upgrade networkx[default]` it upgraded to 2.6.2 and the the commands work.